# Why apt madison?

Tags: apt

A short while ago I asked this question - [Does "apt-get -s upgrade" or some other apt command have an option to list the repositories the packages will be downloaded from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267305/does-apt-get-s-upgrade-or-some-other-apt-command-have-an-option-to-list-the-r), about how to list the repositories packages would be upgraded from.
I have now learned another command, `apt-cache madison` which will list the repos a package will be installed from.

Why a name like `madison` which is in no way related to the task at hand?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `madison` command was added in [apt 0.5.20](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/a/apt/stable_changelog). It produces output that's similar to a then-existing tool called [`madison`](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary#britney) which was used by Debian server administrators. Several of these tools had names which were common female forenames, I don't know if there's a specific history behind that.

The `madison` tool no longer exists but there's a partial reimplementation called [`madison-lite`](https://packages.debian.org/madison-lite) (querying a local package archive, like the original), as well as a script called [`rmadison`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rmadison) in [devscripts](https://packages.debian.org/sid/devscripts) which queries remote servers.

`apt-cache madison` is not emphasized because most of what it displays is also available through `apt-cache showpkg` and `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: From [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary) Britney was "the set of scripts that manages the migration of packages into testing. Originally it was one of many similar FTPmaster scripts with names like `katie` and `madison,` most of which have since been swallowed up by DAK."

Answer (score 21):

From `man apt-cache`:

> apt-cache’s madison command attempts to mimic the output
>   format and a subset of the functionality of the Debian archive
>   management tool, madison. It displays available versions of a
>   package in a tabular format. Unlike the original madison, it can
>   only display information for the architecture for which APT has
>   retrieved package lists (APT::Architecture)